# C# Exchange Server Connection

Tags: c#, service, exchange-server

We have a windows service connecting our exchange web service and retrieving mail items and processing them. Until two days ago it worked fine for 2 years even if the exchange server upgraded 2007 to 2010. But two days ago a strange problem started.

When we use OWA inbox is full of email messages.
When we try to get emails using web service no email item is returned

What would cause such a behaviour?

Thanks

Cause And Solution: The problem caused by the many email messages(in our case about 4700) in the inbox. When you clean your inbox web service will work as expected again.

Comment: Will you be able to post the code of the web service you are using to fetch the emails from the inbox? When you say Web service it is your custom web service and not the OWA right?

Comment: As i know exchange server 2007 and 2010 provide a web service and you can use it to send emails, retrieve emails etc. Just add the web service your project by right clicking the project in solution explorer and selecting add web reference. Then give your web service url generally like https://<your_server>/EWS/exchange.asmx . Then visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408521(EXCHG.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem caused by the many email messages(in our case about 4700) in the inbox. When you clean your inbox web service will work as expected again.